# Modify an array by merging some rows

Tags: python, arrays

I have two arrays

```
label = array([2, 4, 1, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5])

coord = array([[370,  31, 411,  15],
               [246, 122, 316,  73],
               [423, 139, 430, 134],
               [420, 143, 429, 140],
               [ 57, 199,  99, 180],
               [387, 272, 390, 267],
               [390, 277, 393, 272],
               [396, 287, 399, 283],
               [ 75, 318, 102, 295],
               [556, 333, 568, 308]])
```

**coord** is an array of coordinates, each row is a rectangle.
like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtFzn.jpg

my algo should spot seven differencies but it doesn't. So i perfom a kmeans algo, wichi make my array **label**

**label** is the result of a kmeans algo. it shows that row 3-4 and 6,7,8 should be the same rectangle

the idea is to modify my array coord to merge row3/row4 together and row6/row7/row8 together following this pattern **[min_val_col1,max_val_col2,max_val_3,min_val_4]**

the result should be like that => https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QRxz.png

I'm really stuck and i have no idea how proceed. Someone could help me please?

Comment: Can you show some code for the k-means algorithm you used?

Comment: in fact, it's a "fake" because i have some issues with the script. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523182/result-of-kmeans-algo-changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should (I believe) do what you need:

```
u = unique(label)
new_coord = empty((len(u), 4))

i = 0
for j in u:
    rects = compress(label == j, coord, 0)

    mn = rects.min(0)
    mx = rects.max(0)

    new_coord[i] = (mn[0], mx[1], mx[2], mn[3])

    i += 1

print new_coord
```

Basically, it finds the unique values in the `label` array and uses them to pull out each corresponding group of rectangles in the `coord` array. It then works out the minimums and maximums in each column of those rectangle groups, and uses those to populate a new rectangle in the `new_coord` array.

Using this on your example arrays, I get the following output:

```
[[ 387.  287.  399.  267.]
 [ 420.  143.  430.  134.]
 [ 370.   31.  411.   15.]
 [  75.  318.  102.  295.]
 [ 246.  122.  316.   73.]
 [ 556.  333.  568.  308.]
 [  57.  199.   99.  180.]]
```

Please be aware though that I'm relatively new to NumPy - I'm sure this can be made even simpler with some shortcut I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scikit-learn dbscan](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) to cluster the rectangles by distance. I think you need to extract 4 points from each rectangle and label them with the rectangle they belong to, cluster these points, perhaps changing the `eps` until you have 7 rectangles in total.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Python expert, so I'm sure this isn't the most “pythonic” solution in the world, but it seems to work on ordinary lists and lols:

```
gotBox = {}
for i in range(len(label)):
    index = label[i]
    if index in gotBox:
        gotBox[index][0] = min(gotBox[index][0], coord[i][0])
        gotBox[index][1] = max(gotBox[index][1], coord[i][1])
        gotBox[index][2] = max(gotBox[index][2], coord[i][2])
        gotBox[index][3] = min(gotBox[index][3], coord[i][3])
    else:
        gotBox[index] = coord[i]

uniques = [gotBox[i] for i in gotBox]
print uniques
```